# getElementById not working in popup.js [chrome extension]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to replace the word null with the word REPLACED in my chrome extension popup

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1> Wordnik Lookup </h1>
    <p id = "userselect">null</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

My popup.js:

```
document.getElementyById("userselect").innerHTML = "REPLACED!";
```

The error message I get from inspecting the popup

*Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementyById is not a function*

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you have `getElementyById` (the extra y between the t and the B) instead of `getElementById`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two kind of error. One is `typo` (spelling mistake). Another is including `JavaScript` position.

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1> Wordnik Lookup </h1>
    <p id = "userselect">null</p>

     <!--- Kep JavaScript at end. Otherwise listen for DOMContentloaded event --->
     <script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside of `popup.js`

`document.getElementById("userselect").innerHTML = "REPLACED!";`

Comment: Very much appreciated!